# How to loop a script over many files?

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting

I have Gnuplot script **(exe)**, inside this script I supply **X_001** as an input file to be plotted by a certain function giving output file with **X_001.png**. It works well if I manually put the name of the input and output files. i tried to loop this script over the files **{X_001..X_300}**
I wrote this loop

```
for i in X_*; do sed -i 's/X_*/${i}/g' exe ; ./exe ; done
```

but this does not help

this where the change in **exe** script should be made

```
set term png size 1600,1200
set output "X_001.png"
splot 'X_001'
```

Comment: Please show the interesting parts of your Gnuplot script.

Comment: OK I updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer to use a Bash script and a here-document to contain the Gnuplot snippet, directly supplied to `gnuplot`. You don't want to really use `X_*` for the inputs and `X_*.png` for the outputs, because the former includes the latter -- that is, if you run the loop a second time without removing the PNG files, you'll try to use them as data. So, let's say our data files are `X_*.out`, and we wish to plot them to `X_*.png`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LANG=C LC_ALL=C

for data in X_*.out ; do
    [ -r "$data" ] || continue
    png="${data%.*}.png"

    gnuplot <<END-OF-PLOT

        set term png enhanced size 1024,512
        set output "$png"

        set title "$data"
        plot "$data" u 1:2 notitle w lines

END-OF-PLOT
done
```

The `export LANG=C LC_ALL=C` line sets the default C/POSIX locale. It just ensures that if someone else, say your lecturer/teacher/TA, executes the same script, but happens to use a different language (and prefer a different locale to yours), they'll still regenerate the same plots.

(The issue is that some locales use `.` as the decimal points, others use `,`. I avoid that ambiguity by switching to the C/POSIX locale, which is always available. And uses `.` as the decimal point.)

If there are no files matching the glob pattern `X_*.out`, by default Bash iterates once over the loop body with `data` having value `X_*.out` itself. The `[ -r "$data" ] || continue` test checks if there is a readable file named in the `data` variable. If not, it skips to next iteration (the rest of the loop body is not executed for this value).

Note the `png` assignment: `${data%.*}` evaluates to the value of variable `data` -- here the data file name --, except that everything starting at the last `.` is removed. (If there is no `.` in `data`, then nothing is removed.)

Thus, in Bash, `${data%.*}.png` evaluates to the value of `data`, except that if it has a filename suffix, it is replaced with `.png`. If it does not have a filename suffix, `.png` is appended to it.

The `<<END-MARKER` is used to start the [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) in Bash. The contents, up to (but not including) a line that begins with `END-MARKER`, is supplied as input. However, variable expansion is done within this text, so you can use the `$variable` or `${variable}` syntax (and others) in the here document, and they will be replaced with their contents.

Note that unlike in Bash command-line commands, quotes in Bash here documents are kept. So, if `png` has value `X_001.out`, then `set output "$png"` expands to, and Gnuplot sees, as `set output "X_001.out"`.

Answer (score 3):

Make a template script, for example, `exe-template`. In the template script use placeholders for the name of the input file and output file; for example, use `X_input` for the input file and `X_input.png` for the output file.

```
set term png size 1600,1200
set output "X_input.png"
splot 'X_input'
```

Then, in the loop, use `sed` to replace `X_input` with the name of the data file and write the resulting modified script to a temporary file, for example `exe-tmp`:

```
for i in X_[0-9][0-9][0-9] ; do
  sed -e 's/X_input/'${i}'/g' exe-template >exe-tmp
  chmod 755 ./exe-tmp
  ./exe-tmp
done
```